# Installing Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (on a part of secondary disk) alongside Windows 10 (installed on primary disk)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 7570. It has a 256G SSD and 1TB HDD with Windows 10 installed on the SSD. I partitioned the 1TB HDD to create ~500GB space for a potential Linux installation (using Windows Disk Management, which now shows this space as unallocated), the rest is being used by Windows 10 for my Windows data.

Now I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on this 500GB space, but am not sure how I should be going about the partitioning and bootloader business - esp. reading a few articles on the web is leaving me a bit confused including would it be Windows Boot Manager or GRUB that would start the system? When I started the Ubuntu installation I got a message asking if I wanted to install 3rd party hardware drivers to which I said Yes (it has a NVIDIA GEForce 940MX Card), so it asked me for a password to disable secure boot which I gave.
Please see the screenshots below which indicate the way system is partitioned. Also the device for bootloader installation drop-down in the screens below has the following options:

/dev/sdb ATA Micron 1100 SATA (256GB) ---->SSD

/dev/sda ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (1.0TB) -----> HDD

/dev/sdb1 - Windows Boot Manager

/dev/sdb4

/dev/sdb5

/dev/sdb6

Can someone please guide me on the exact steps I need to take? I have data on my Windows system so I can't afford to mess around. Would appreciate right guidance on this.

Thanking in anticipation :)

[image: Partitioning picture 1]
[image: Partitioning picture 2]

Comment: I recommend you make a backup before proceeding. If you have important data, you should be making backups anyway.

Comment: Some questions : Does the "If you have a OEM-preinstalled copy of Windows 8 or later" work well for Windows 10 also, and even if it's a secondary disk. Also do I need to disable fast boot permanently on Windows? Will I see windows boot manager or GRUB on bootup? Is it possible/cleaner to do it using Windows boot manager?

Comment: Yes, "Windows 8 and later" includes Windows 10. For the other questions I'm not sure, but I don't think it's possible to boot Linux from the Windows Boot Manager.